# command line typescript scripting in angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, scripting

In an angular project, a script is required to do some conversions on the json exported in typescript file.

We need to create a command line script in the project which can read typescript files and create output files.

What are possible approaches to achieve this? How can we run typescript code from command line?

Comment: Did you try `tsc --watch` ?

Comment: Please be more specific. Angular already compiles TS files.

Comment: @Maryannah Angular compiles ts files when run from ng serve or ng build etc. I want to compile from command line and run from command line, not using server/ browser.

Comment: Then run `tsc` as stated previously. This is what Angular CLI uses under the hood.